# Comunication issue Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, email

I'm getting below errors during new customer registration and during using contact us form:

> We can't process your request right now. Sorry, that's all we know.
>
> We can't save the customer.

Comment: Have you add additional fields to contact us page?

Comment: no at all, https://herara.com/contact

Comment: Other emails working or not?

Comment: non of the store emails are working - i'm using Gmail SMTP pro only test emails is working

Comment: You should be start your store email.

Comment: @ S H Patel, what do you mean?